# How to use loops to create multiple tables from data query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have posts split into alphabetical groups like this.

A

B

C

E

Each letter needs 1 table.

Each row has 2 columns title and tags.

How do i add the table to the loop correctly so each letter has 1 table?

```
<table style=" width:100%; table-layout:fixed " > 

</table>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% cur_letter = nil %>

<% @posts.each do |t| %>

      <% title_letter = t.title[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? t.title[0].capitalize : "#" %> 


      <% if title_letter != cur_letter %>
        <% cur_letter = title_letter %>
        <%= cur_letter %>
      <% end %>


      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%"><%= t.title %></td>

        <td style="width:50%"><%= t.tags %></td>
      </tr>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it possible a title could start with a number like "6 ways to a better..."?

Comment: Yes i need it to display # for any titles that start with a number.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer to take that into account. Also do you see that the data structure you are asking for basically means you have an inner and outer loop? Outer loop is the alphabetical, inner is all of the posts in that letter group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**: I changed @post to @posts where stylistically appropriate

Rather than doing lots of gymnastics in your view, you could assemble the data how you want it before you pass it to the view:

```
@posts = Post.all.group_by {|post| post.title.downcase[0]}

# => {"a" => [<post....#array of post beginning with "A"], "b" => [post... #and so on... ]}
```

This will create a hash with a key representing each first letter with the value being all the Post objects whose title starts with that letter. Now with that passed to the view you could then iterate over them in a couple of ways.

In the interest of someone finding this later and running into the very real possibility that the field they are grouping by has a null value somewhere, I'll add this to cover all cases including nil values:

```
@posts = Post.all.group_by do |post|
 if post.title == nil  
   post.title = ' '    
 end    
 post.title.downcase[0]
```

end

Now on to the view...

If you want just the letters that exist, i.e. if you don't have any posts that begin their title with "X", then you can just iterate through the keys

```
<% @posts.keys.sort.each do |key| %>  #this is where the sorting a-z happens

    <h2><%= key.upcase %></h2><br>

    <table style=" width:100%; table-layout:fixed " > 

       <% @posts[key].each do |post| %>
          <tr>  
              <td> <%= post.title %> </td>
              <td> <%= post.tags  %> </td>
          </tr>
       <% end %>

    </table>

<% end %>
```

I've left out the styling details of your table as that is up to you.

If you want every letter listed, even if there are no Post titles beginning with that letter you can just do:

```
 <% (('0'..'9').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a).each do |letter| %>
    #this generates ['0','1','2'....'z']
    <h2><%= letter.upcase %></h2><br>

    <table style=" width:100%; table-layout:fixed " > 

       <% @posts[letter].each do |post| %>
          <tr>  
              <td> <%= post.title %> </td>
              <td> <%= post.tags  %> </td>
          </tr>
       <% end %>

    </table>

<% end %>
```

This would give you:

**A**

A post beginning with "a"      | some tags

Another post starting with "a" | some tags

**B**

**C**

**D**

Decidedly starts with "d"      | some tags

Dis post starts with "d" ;-)   | some tags

**E**

etc...

The problem with this style is that if you have any posts that start with a non-letter/non-number character, you won't see them unless you include all of those characters in your outer loop array. That is why I would do it the first way, as that represents the data that exists rather than guessing what data might exist.

Comment: So in the first answer it doesn't matter what your post titles start with, rails will just take the first character and group those posts together. Then you are just sorting the keys alphabetically and iterating through them. The second answer creates the array of numbers and letters. But you could still be tripped up by a weird character at the beginning of your post, like " :-) .."

Comment: Ok your way makes way more sense. One question what do you mean by this "a" => [<post....#array of post beginning with "A"] I do this for each letter right but i'm not sure what you mean by post....#array of post do i have to manually put every post under the correct letter. I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: That is just a comment, sorry. I'm just showing what you get as a return value. I'll make that clearer in an edit.

Comment: Do this, it will help a lot: go to the rails console and enter the `@post = Post.all.group_by {|post| post.title.downcase[0]}` code. See what it generates? Also a caveat, the `group_by` will fail if you have a post who's title is nil or null. So either validate that a post must have a title, or you would have to do a bit fancier query...

Comment: Ok so I set everything up and i get undefined local variable or method `letter'

Comment: Just deleted my comment, it SHOULD work without any forced interpolation... let me experiment...

Comment: Your error should reference a line number, can you tell where it's throwing the error for `letter`?

Comment: Ok i'm using your first method where it only shows the lettters that have posts. Its the <h2><%= letter.upcase %></h2>

Comment: My bad, I copied that from below. It should be key.upcase. Will fix it.

Comment: Thank you everything works now. I appreciate you taking all that time to help.

Comment: My pleasure, I faced a very similar problem in a Rails view and I refactored it similar to the above answer after i realized my original code was very clunky. I try to always let the controller build the data structure I need and then I only need the minimal amount of view code to display it.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted your comment, But you asked for a way to group all the posts that start with numbers into a '#' key in the hash, this is how:  `@post = Post.all.group_by {|post| ('a'..'z').include? post.title.downcase[0] ? post.title.downcase[0] : post.title = '#'}`

Comment: Ah ha! Scratch that, you can't use the ternary operator `?` in the group_by statement above, because it returns `true` or `false` too soon. So you'd have to do it with slightly less concise `if then` statement: `@posts = Post.all.group_by {|post| if ('a'..'z').include? post.title.downcase[0] then post.title.downcase[0] else post.title = '#' end }`

Comment: That works except that it changes the title of the link to #. So if the post title is called 10 Things to Do it displays to the screen a a single hashtag.

Comment: hmm.. unexpected output. guess that makes sense since I told it to change post.title to '#'. one second...

Comment: Ok, easy fix: `@posts = Post.all.group_by {|post| if ('a'..'z').include? post.title.downcase[0] then post.title.downcase[0] else '#' end }`  We just want the group_by to return something to sort by, so it will do that instead of changing the post.title.

Comment: Just posted a question and got an answer: you can use the ternary statement, I just didn't have parens in the right place, so equivalent would be : `@posts = Post.all.group_by {|post| ('a'..'z').include?(post.title.downcase[0]) ? post.title.downcase[0] : '#' }

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your posts are already ordered alphabetically. You'll want to:

1. Open the first table.
2. Every time you hit a new letter, close the existing table and open a new one.
3. At the end, close the last table.

Code will look something like this:

```
<% cur_letter = nil %>
<table style=" width:100%; table-layout:fixed " > 
<% @posts.each do |t| %>

      <% title_letter = t.title[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? t.title[0].capitalize : "#" %> 


      <% if title_letter != cur_letter %>
        <% cur_letter = title_letter %>
        <%= cur_letter %>
        <!-- You're switching letters here, so close the current table and start a new one. -->
        </table>
        <table style=" width:100%; table-layout:fixed " > 
      <% end %>


      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%"><%= t.title %></td>

        <td style="width:50%"><%= t.tags %></td>
      </tr>

<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesn't work because i end up with each row having having a table attached to it table attached to it. So if there is 60 rows for letter A then there is 60 tables because each row has a table.

Comment: See my answer. You don't need to do any of this ` <% if title_letter != cur_letter %>` business, even if you do it joshua's way. Better to loop through the alphabet and then create each table as needed.